# Should exceptions without messages be thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Should exceptions without messages ever be thrown? In what cases? For example, when subclassing `Exception`, should a constructor with no parameters even be given?

```
public class LexerException extends Exception {
    public LexerException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class LexerException extends Exception {
    public LexerException() {
        super();
    }
    public LexerException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an entirely subjective, situational question.

Comment: Generally, you should avoid custom exceptions. Use ones that already exist.

Comment: Why should I avoid custom exceptions?

Comment: @mre that makes no sense to avoid custom exceptions if none of the exceptions provided to you are meaningful for your context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should exceptions without messages ever be thrown?  In what cases?

An exception without a message will be thrown any time some code instantiates and throws an exception without a message.  Anyone can write code like that.

Of course, if the exception that you are trying to throw does not allow you to instantiate it without a message ... or a with `null` message ... then you can't.  But I've never come across an exception class that *insists* that the exception is non-null.

One case where exceptions *typically* have no message is `NullPointerException` when it is thrown by the JVM itself.

---

If you are asking *should it ...* in the sense of whether it is good practice to write code that throws exceptions without a message, the answer is (IMO) No.  But you can make up your own mind.  (I guess, if the exception name says all that there is to be said, then a message would be redundant.  However, it is always useful to have extra information in the stacktrace when debugging.)

---

Re these comments:

> Generally, you should avoid custom exceptions. Use ones that already exist. –  mre
>
> Why should I avoid custom exceptions? –  Kyranstar

The point is that *before* you code a custom exception, you should look to see if there is an existing exception that means the same thing as your proposed new one.  For example, don't write a custom `IllegalLexerArgumentException` exception when there is an existing `IllegalArgumentException` that would serve your purposes.

Why?

1. For the same reasons that we don't write (say) custom collection classes without good reason.  It is a bad idea to write unnecessary code, 'cos that is just more code to compile and test, more space at runtime, more code for the maintainer to read, etc.
2. Because having lots of exception classes that mean the same thing can make exception handling messy.  This effect gets worse as you combine / reuse more libraries to make large applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give the exception any message so you can pop-up the message into anther position when you get the error, but it's recommended to give every exception you create a message and to create an instance of this exception and to throw it.

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation explicitly states there is a single case triggering the exception, then IMHO it is not require to have a message in the exception. Otherwise, it is. A good rule of thumb is: Make it easy for whoever is going to use/debug that code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, honestly I've just searched our code and we use Exceptions without messages, but they are *really obvious* ones. Like:

```
 UsernameCantBeEmptyException// example only
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the use case. The `NullPointerException` for instance has no message. What could be helpful? No idea. On the other hand there where versions of java where the `ClassCastException` had no message. That's extremly annoing as the type that should be casted is hart to figure out and is available to the program.

As long as I've no idea for a use case where skipping the message seems appropiate, I'd provide no empty constructor. AFAIK a lexer figures out things like this variable has that type and thus that acion is appropriate or not. This would indicate that the exception message might even have to be presented to he end user. In such a case even localization might be mandatory. If so even some 'factory infrastructre' might be a good idea.

On custom exceptions in general: There's been a tendency to do that to often and then many figured out that in fact no custom exceptions have ever been needed. And in fact there are even hudge programs that need not a single one. On business I work on a 200kLOC program and I don't think we have one. But for sub-systems with specific needs on handling (Like catching all the LexerException to show them in a specific way, separate them from programming bugs in your own code, whatsoever) it might make much sense to have a few. I'm working on a small OSS project and there I have even more than one. But you should always keep in mind that additional exception type must make the exception handling simpler not more complicated. If you often have several catch block one after another, then your definitly on the wrong track. That's a typical symptom of unnecessary custom exceptions.